# Tensorflow GPU fails to find CUDA in windows

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have downloaded cuDNN v5.1 and CUDA 8.0 and also moved the folders lib. include, and bin to the Cuda directory where i installed it.

```
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\tensorflow>python try.py

I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stre
am_executor\dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library cublas64_80.dll locally

I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stre
am_executor\dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library cudnn64_5.dll locally

I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stre
am_executor\dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library cufft64_80.dll locally

I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stre
am_executor\dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library nvcuda.dll locally

I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stre
am_executor\dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library curand64_80.dll
locally
Extracting /tmp/data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz

E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stre
am_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:509] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE



Is there any solution for that ??
```

Comment: Does the machine have a [compatible GPU installed](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)?

Comment: yes it's compatible  GeForce GT 740M 3.0